# SendTemplateNotificationAsync not sending messages to Azure Notification Hub

Tags: android, azure, .net-core, push-notification

New to push notifications in Azure. I have a .NET Core API setup to send messages to a notification hub.

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class SendNotificationController : ControllerBase
    {
        private NotificationHubClient PublicHub;
        public SendNotificationController()
        {
            PublicHub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(DispatcherConstants.FullAccessConnectionString, DispatcherConstants.NotificationHubName);
      
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Send/title={Title}&message={Message}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string Title, string Message)
        {
            await SendTemplateNotificationsAsync(Title, Message);
            return Ok();
        }

        private async Task SendTemplateNotificationsAsync(string Title, string Message)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> templateParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            try
            {
                templateParameters["title"] = $"{Title}";
                templateParameters["message"] = $"{Message}";

                var outcome = await PublicHub.SendTemplateNotificationAsync(templateParameters);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed to send template notification: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

    }
```

I'm running my API locally in debug (https), using a Swagger page to test. I've triple-checked the connection string and hub name.

The outcome is always "enqueued", success = 0, fail = 0 and no exception is thrown. I get a tracking ID. I can successfully send test messages to an Android device from the Azure portal, but it doesn't work when trying to send from my API using this method.

Based on what I've seen while researching this approach - I must be missing something simple but I'm not sure where to look...